# Is there a symbol library for TikZ or circuitikz that contains German house electric planning symbols?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

The symbology I am looking for is used to plan German electric house cabling when building or renovating. Unfortunately I couldn‘t find a DIN or ISO reference, but this is the symbology I am looking for:

https://elektriker-rv.de/anleitung-elektroplanung-eigenheim/

Comment: Hi, no, they're not in `circuitikz` (and for what I could deduce, they're more as symbols for plans more than for circuits.). I see the more fit for a shape library than as a possible extension for `circuitikz` (but I will help if I can, you can start with the block and antennas shapes).

Comment: You could use a graphics editor and create images for each symbol. put them into nodes and figure out where the connection points are relative to the compass anchors.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for your offer. Would you suggest to make shapes for PGF directly? And yes these are more meant to be added to a floor plan, but later they have interconnections, but different than in a circuit drawing.

Comment: @JohnKormylo sure, thanks for that approach. I could also find a PDF and extract them from there. I was just thinking there might have been a more native approach.

Comment: Well, you could start with circuiikz shapes also, so you have some premade utility macros... But then you need to load circuitkz also.

Comment: I did write a tutorial on how to create circutikz components (http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm), although some of it may be obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is really "no, not that I know".

On one side, the symbols are really not used in "a circuit" (a circuit describes electrical connections, not spatial ones); on the other side, I understand that there are *some* points of contact between those symbols and the circuit symbols and that reusing some of the macros os `circuitikz` can be helpful.

Finally, I feel that a library of symbols addressing the question would probably fit more as a "parallel" one to `circuitikz`, more than part of it.